# Python and MySQL Incorrect string value

Tags: python, mysql, character-encoding

I am aware this question has been asked before, but the solutions presented don't seem to work.
I am trying to insert text to a table but I keep getting this:

```
Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xEBrt of...' for column 'title' at row 1
```

The character in question is: ë

This is how the table looks:

```
CREATE TABLE `rstest_article` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `source_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `link` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `content` longtext NOT NULL,
  `description` longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `rstest_article_89f89e85` (`source_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `source_id_refs_id_c47b907b` FOREIGN KEY (`source_id`) REFERENCES `rstest_source` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=606 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I am grabbing the text from another database with the same charset, like so:

```
_cursor.execute('SELECT title,link,content,descr,channel FROM articles')
    rows = _cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        article = Article(source=src,title=row[0],link=row[1],content=row[2],description=row[3])
        article.save()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the `\\` escaping something?  Try adding backticks.

Comment: You're going to have to let us know what that string was supposed to be, and show the code you are using.

Comment: Where is the text coming from? How are you trying to insert it in the database? What's missing from the previous times the question has been asked? (My guess is that you're trying to insert iso8859-1 text into a utf-8 database column)

Answer (score 4):

Try to change collation of your table.

```
ALTER TABLE rstest_article CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE UTF8_general_ci;
```

or change collation only for one column.

```
ALTER TABLE rstest_article MODIFY COLUMN title varchar(200) DEFAULT '' CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL;
```

And you can check also in your python code, how you store title.

```
title = u'unicode_string'.encode('unicode_escape')
```

Comment: I changed the collation, but got the same results.
The encoding got rid of that error, but now I get a UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x95 in position 3625: ordinal not in range(128)
Any more tips?

Comment: You need to decode the string again when you go to use it, your trying to either print or write to file and python defaults to system default (ascii)

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape special characters,Mysqldb has escape_string function for escaping special characters as:
Assuming a variable  title storing string that needs to be entered in title column of db.

title = MySQLdb.escape_string(title)

In order to escape **' and "** from the title string you have to create query something like:

q = ''' Insert into rstest_article(title) values("%s") ''' % (title)

This should solve the problem :)